# Try/catch is not getting the inner exception thrown by Assert in c#

Tags: c#, try-catch, assert

I am working on a project which will run the given unit tests in production. I want to return the result of unit test hence using try/catch. I am assuming if any assertion fail it will throw an exception. And I can return the error as exception.message()

```
try {
   callingUnitTestMethod();
   return new TestResult {Name = "TestName", Status = "Success", Error = "NA"};
} catch(Exception ex) {
   return new TestResult {Name = "TestName", Status = "Fail", Error = ex.Message};
}
```

Now this is giving the same exception for every method - "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.". But I want the assertion message which we get while running the unit tests from testExplorer. How can we get the proper exception?

Note: I tried ex.InnerException.ToString() as well. But the InnerException is null.

Comment: Has TestResult class a default constructor?

Comment: "the InnerException is null" is very strange because it's a mandatory parameter to all `TargetInvocationException` constructors (although it cannot be omitted, it can be explicitly passed as `null`, but that should be quite unusual)

Comment: @McNets The TestResult class is created by me. It's a POJO to send the result properly.

Comment: Yes but, has a default constructor?

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually innerException is working for test methods. I am using reflection to get all the methods and Unit Test class was containing non test methods as well hence it was giving it null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to specifically catch `TargetInvocationException`, and access the `.InnerException` as the cause, i.e.

```cs
try
{
   callingUnitTestMethod();
   return new TestResult {Name = "TestName", Status = "Success", Error = "NA"};
}
catch (TargetInvocationException tex)
{
   return new TestResult {Name = "TestName", Status = "Fail",
       Error = tex.InnerException.Message};
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return new TestResult {Name = "TestName", Status = "Fail", Error = ex.Message};
}
```

Comment: The `TargetInvocationException` inherits its `InnerException` property from `Exception`, so there's no difference between catching it specifically or catching the base class and reading polymorphically.

Comment: @BenVoigt the difference isn't in the API signature; it is in the **semantics**; a `TargetInvocationException` tells you that something happened when calling a reflection call, and that the real something is in the `.InnerException`; *that* is why we only want to do this for the specific exception type - if something *else* happened: the problem is the *outer* exception